# How do i solve No Package.JSON found error in react js?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I ran `npx create-react-app react-app` in cmd and though it created the app in this directory but it was not fully installed. `59 packages are looking for funding` it says. I tried to `npm start` but it says `D:\ReactJs\react-app>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start`
The full error message is :

```
D:\ReactJs>npx create-react-app react-app

Creating a new React app in D:\ReactJs\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\ReactJs\react-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\ReactJs\react-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\ReactJs\react-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
added 1612 packages from 750 contributors and audited 921729 packages in 728.54s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

D:\ReactJs> npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T20_44_56_644Z-debug.log

D:\ReactJs>cd react-app

D:\ReactJs\react-app>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T20_46_12_290Z-debug.log
```

Comment: As the log shows, you might be having an outdated version of `create-react-app`. Try updating it by using the command `npm install -g create-react-app` and try once gain.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove global version of create-react-app script `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then use `npx create-react-app react-app` again.
It should work.

Comment: i'v installed it. Now it says: `C:\Users\Ahnaaf Al Rafee>npx create-react-app react-app
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ahnaaf'
command not found: create-react-app`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Now you should install it again `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `npx create-react-app react-app`